# alternative for CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP for APIs below 18

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am syncing contacts with my server and I need any change in contact book(insert/delete/update) to be synced with the server. For this I am using 'CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP' and comparing it with timestamp in my database which is working fine.

But the problem is CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP is added in API 18 and I need to give support from API 8.

so I am looking for an alternative of CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP for APIs below 18.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? If you found any, Could you please share it to me.

Comment: Sorry dude, there is no alternate solution. I had to do it the hard way i.e take all contacts from phone book and compare it with contacts in DB one-by-one to look for any change.

Comment: @Sarang did you find any solution to this?